# Tegmark's level 1 universe: how many universes?

Tags: cosmology, universe, big-bang, cosmological-inflation, multiverse

In "Our Mathematical Universe" Tegmark claims that inflation theory implies the existence of an infinite set of universes.

My simple question is: what kind of infinity, and why that kind ?

I am not sure whether the amount of universes at any point in time is infinite in this model, but supposing that that amount is infinite at some specific time/moment $t_0$, is it *countably infinite* ? Or larger ?

My guess is that it is countably infinite (because I guess one starts from some finite configuration, and the generation process is in some sense countable), but I have no precise reason at all ...

Answer (score 1):

Let us remind that Tegmark's level one universe has the same laws we do, but different initial conditions. It all depends on the fine structure of the universe. If the initial conditions can only be discrete, and the universe finite, then  the number of configurations is countable. If it is infinite it will also be continuous because the set of all  infinite list of digits has the cardinality of the real numbers. And if the universe is continuous and infinite the cardinality will be that of the set of functions from reals to reals, that is, the cardinality will be that of the power-set of the real numbers.

Comment: Could you explain your first possibility ? Why does "discrete initial conditions" lead to "countable number of universes" ?

Comment: only if the universe is finite. You can order the boxes (spacetime locations) and also the initial conditions in each box, so you can map that to the natural numbers

Comment: I still do not understand; spacetime locations of what ? And what do you map exactly to the natural numbers ? Thanks !